# 1st post review from community wiki?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I'm not sure what I am seeing here:

[image]

I doubt the community wiki asked question in the body of another question.

Was this a test? If so, how does one respond when the only two options are "No Action Needed" and "Skip"?

For completeness here's the original question and review:

- [How do I dump the data of some SQLite3 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4017799

Comment: This is a question *Post Made Community Wiki by James Chen* which as been already deleted by moderator, which has been used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Flagging the answer is the right action (there is a flag button below the post). He is essentially asking a question and posting it as an answer. I do agree that the "No Action Needed" and "Skip" buttons are too prominent that they can overshadow the other buttons that normally exist on a post.

> [image]

The reason why this answer is community wiki is because the question is already a CW post. Any further answer to a CW question automatically becomes CW. It wasn't that the community user asked a question. It was an answer by a normal user turned into community wiki. Try not to confuse the two.

**Review trick**: One way to check if this is an audit is simply to click the link to the answer and see if the answer exists. If it doesn't (given that you have <10k rep on SO), you can tell that it is a review audit.

Answer (score 0):

This was an audit. If the post does not answer the question, downvote it or flag it for moderator attention. This will pass the audit and it should show a "Congratulations!" message.